# Where do I place code to connect popup data in Google extension to IndexedDB?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I have a Google extension that I have been working on. I need to be able to store the data that appears in a popup into IndexedDB in Chrome so that I can access it later. What code do I need to add to do this and where do I add it, background.js or popup.js?

Comment: Assuming "Google extension" is a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), simply put the code in your popup's js script. Currently the question is either too trivial or incomplete, in in which case you need to edit it and describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback